# Merge [kotlin-coroutines] and [kotlinx.coroutines]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

There are two tags used for questions on Kotlin coroutines: [kotlinx.coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlinx.coroutines) and [kotlin-coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin-coroutines). They are almost indistinguishable in scope, but precisely speaking the latter is more general and subsumes the former (`kotlinx.coroutines` is an extension library, but there are several founding concepts that are built into the language and the Kotlin standard library).

[kotlinx.coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlinx.coroutines) has established itself as the go-to tag for all things coroutines in Kotlin, even those that are about the core concepts. It has 290 questions.

[kotlin-coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin-coroutines) has just 9 questions.

Since the distinction between the extension library and the language feature is unimportant and most users aren't even aware of it, there should ideally be just one tag for all coroutine-related questions.

The situation is currently awkward because the narrower tag is by far the more popular one.

Would a good approach be to declare these two tags as synonyms?