# Accept synonym request: [kotlinx.coroutines] -> [kotlin-coroutines]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

In a [recent question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377593/merge-kotlin-coroutines-and-kotlinx-coroutines) I presented the problem with [kotlinx.coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlinx.coroutines) being a concept almost identical to [kotlin-coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin-coroutines), the two having something like a 98% overlap, and users applying the former tag even to questions that are not about the `kotlinx.coroutines` extension library, but are related to the language feature of Kotlin coroutines.

My question received a favorable score, so I created a [tag synonym request](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kotlin-coroutines/synonyms) and now I'd like to get it accepted.

In more detail:

`kotlinx.coroutines` is the name of the extension library which supports the language feature of coroutines in Kotlin. The language itself and the standard library contain several founding concepts, though, which could be theoretically used without the extension library, so the name "`kotlinx.coroutines`" isn't appropriate for all possible questions on Kotlin coroutines. On the other hand, the tag [kotlin-coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin-coroutines) gives a perfectly sufficient focus to any coroutine-related question and there is never a need to specifically state that the question is about something in the extension library.

The ideal end-state would be that only the tag [kotlin-coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin-coroutines) exists and I thought the proper way to get there was to declare [kotlinx.coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlinx.coroutines) as its synonym.

Comment: To clarify - it sounds like you're saying that despite the similar names they're actually not the same thing? However, people are confusing the two and mis-tagging them?

Comment: `kotlinx.coroutines` is the name of the extension library which supports the language feature of coroutines in Kotlin. The language itself and the standard library contain several founding concepts and you can actually use coroutines without the extension library. But `kotlinx.coroutines` established itself as the main tag for all things coroutine, whether or not it involves anything from the extension li,, while the proper tag `kotlin-coroutines`, stands rarely used.

Comment: Since this question is getting downvoted, can I get an explanation what exactly aspect of the previous question on this topic was approved (20 upvotes)? The current situation is less than ideal, but I'm not getting explicit feedback on how the community would like to handle this.

Comment: Not my downvote, but on meta, usually we have just one post. Those users probably thought you were duplicating the requests. I've closed this as a dupe of the other for now. Having just one post is enough, if people see that, they'll accept the synonym request

Comment: @BhargavRao I'm just not acquainted with the process. My first question was asking how to proceed and this question was supposed to be the followup where I ask to accept the synonym. At the time of the first question there was no synonym request, so now in spite of the 20 upvotes on the first question, there are zero votes on the synonym request.

Comment: Yeah, synonym requests are a bit weird. There are too many restrictions on it. I had asked this one when I was new with the process  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312430. I'll try to look at it sometime this weekend and approve it.

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Sorry, didn't have time last weekend. (Elections and stuff). I will try to look at it this week.

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks for taking action, as an answerer on Kotlin coroutines I can confirm that the experience is much better now.